# Function for changing numbers with React doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I'm trying to change number stored in a variable by clicking a button but the first time I click the button, it doesn't change the value of the variable but the second one does. I change the number in increments of 1, so when I click the button its `currentNumber += 1` and I run a `console.log` after it to see if it changes. The first time I click it, it prints the default value, and the second time that I click it is when it actually changes, and it's messing up the intended functionality of my code. I'm using React for this.

```js
constructor(props) {
     super(props);
        this.state = {
            currentSize: parseInt(this.props.size),
            min: 4,
            max: 40,
        }
    };
    
    
increaseSize(){
        this.setState({currentSize: this.state.currentSize + 1}, function(){
            if(this.state.currentSize >= this.state.max){
                this.state.currentSize = this.state.max;
                this.state.isRed = true;
            } else if(this.state.currentSize < this.state.max){
                this.state.isRed = false;
            }
        });
        console.log(this.state.currentSize);
    };
    
render() {
        var isBold = this.state.bold ? 'normal' : 'bold';
        var currentSize = this.state.currentSize;
        var textColor = this.state.isRed ? 'red' : 'black';

        return(
               <div>
               <button id="decreaseButton" hidden='true' onClick={this.decreaseSize.bind(this)}>-</button>
               <span id="fontSizeSpan" hidden='true' style={{color: textColor}}>{currentSize}</span>
               <button id="increaseButton" hidden='true' onClick={this.increaseSize.bind(this)}>+</button>
               <span id="textSpan" style={{fontWeight: isBold, fontSize: currentSize}} onClick={this.showElements.bind(this)}>{this.props.text}</span>
               </div>
        );
    }
```

The number in the variable is then displayed but the one being displayed has a different value to the one inside the variable

[image]

As you can see in the picture, the number displayed is 26 but in the variable its 25.

Additionally, you can see that I set a min and max value for the counter. When it reaches either value, it goes 1 further in the display, but not in the console. So in the display it stops at 3 and 41 but in the console it stops at 4 and 40.

What am I doing wrong?

edit: the default value is 16, and that's whats printed to the console the first time I click the button, which is why its not working properly.

Comment: First, you should never mutate React state. In the `increaseSize()` function, you assign values to `this.state` which is mutating it. If you want to change the state, use `this.setState()`. Second, the `console.log` in `increaseSize()` is being called BEFORE the state changes, because `this.setState()` returns before the state has been modified. If you want code to run after the state changes, put the code into `this.setState()`'s callback.

Comment: @Sidney Thank you. I fixed the setState issue. That was an overlook on my part. I'm still running into the number issue, however. To which code do you refer with the second point? 

edit: nevermind. I figured it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the functional version of `setState()` in order to get a hold of prev state values -- because React handles state changes asynchronously, you can't guarantee their values when you set them; This is also the cause where you are using the `console.log`. Instead go for something like:

```
increaseSize(){
const aboveMax = this.state.currentSize >= this.state.max;

this.setState( prevState => ({
    currentSize: aboveMax ? prevState.max : prevState.currentSize + 1,
    isRed: aboveMax
})
, () => console.log(this.state.currentSize) );
};
```

Or, move the console statement to the `render()` method if you don't want to the `setState()` callback function.

See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Don't forget to set `isRed` in your constructor as well :)

Comment: I did remember the `isRed` prop, I just didn't include it for purposes of this post, but thanks for the reminder. This code works great, with the only caveat that when I decrease back to 39 the number is still red, until I go down to 38. Any clues? 

edit: I reformated the decreaseSize function to your format and it fixed the issue. Probably should've done that earlier. Thank you very much for you help.